# Expressing principal value of integral as real/imaginary

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

How is it that we can express

$$
\mathrm{p.v.}\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac{\cos 3x}{x^2+4}=\Re \ \mathrm{p.v.}\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac{e^{3xi}}{x^2+4}
$$

while we cannot for

$$
\mathrm{p.v.}\int_{-\infty} ^{\infty} \frac{\cos 3x}{x+i}
$$

How do we determine whether the integrand is real valued or not?

Comment: The integrand of the second is not real-valued.

Comment: The problem I have is that I cannot tell when the integrand is equal real or not. What should I do to determine that?

Comment: In these cases, you know that $\cos (3x)$ is real for real $x$, and $x^2+4$ is also real. But $x+i$ is not real for $x\in\mathbb{R}$, so the second integrand is not real. Generally, it can be more difficult to determine whether the integrand is real-valued or not.

Comment: Is there a sort of standard approach to determine whether the integrand is real-valued or not?